# MCmoding Как поставить табличку и задать ей текст

Tags: java

Пишу я мод для Minecraft. Дошло до момента, когда я добавил в деревню новые дома. Вдруг, мне понадобилось установить табличку, и написать на ней текст. Установить то я смог, а вот как текст установить, не разобрался.
Ставлю табличку методом World.setBlockState.
Изучил кучу классов связанных с табличкой, но не разобрался...

Есть идеи или варианты, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено! Нужно было задать NBT тэги.